# 'date must not be blank' but it isn't blank (ActiveRecord validation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Here's a Ruby function in a rails app in the class that corresponds to my table:

```
 def self.import(file)
    line = 1
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      reading_hash = row.to_hash
      logger.debug("line #{line}")
      logger.debug(reading_hash)
      Reading.create!(reading_hash)
      line = line + 1
    end # end CSV.foreach
  end
```

I see this value in the debugger:

```
reading_hash = Hash (5 elements)
 'date' => 9/19/2015
 'name' => Vayeilech
 'reading' => Hosea 14:2-10; Micah 7:18-20; Joel 2:15-27 | Shabbat Shuva
 'assigned_to' => Spencer Ross (20th bar mitzvah anniversary) Gene Achter (deferred, please find another day for him)
 'comments' => Shabbat Shuvah
```

I also print the hash to the logger:

```
  {"date"=>"9/19/2015", "name"=>"Vayeilech", "reading"=>"Hosea 14:2-10; Micah 7:18-20; Joel 2:15-27 | Shabbat Shuva", "assigned_to"=>"Spencer Ross (20th bar mitzvah anniversary) Gene Achter (deferred, please find another day for him)", "comments"=>"Shabbat Shuvah"}
```

But if I continue into `create!`, I'll get:

```
Validation failed: Date can't be blank
```

This happens on the third record, the first two work fine.

Perhaps I should also cite the validation:

```
  validates :date, presence: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you format your csv dates to one of the below formats? That will make it work. Any of these formats will insert the date you want:

`2015/09/19`
`2015/9/19`
`19/09/2015`

Comment: Yes, I should be able to persuade Google sheets. Thanks.

Comment: You can format you date in before_validation callback if you cannt  persuade Google sheets

Comment: Why is the error 'blank' instead, I whine, 'invalid date format'.

Answer (score 0):

Put quotes around the date. I think that will fix it.

Comment: OK, but why do the first two work without the quotes? Also, in the debugger, _none_ of the attributes are set at the validation point, not just the date.

Comment: 9/19/2015 is an invalid date, can you verify if this is the reason you are getting the error?  you will get error on Date.parse('9/19/2015') but not on Date.parse('19/9/2015')

Comment: @zahid see accepted answer. All is well with ISO dates.